# Powershell - Count lines in files excluding/including certain lines

Tags: powershell, count, line, counting

I have the script below that will count ALL the lines of all my files in the directory and sub-directory.
Works fine and creates the output file fine.
The issue I'm having now, is that all the files have comments and executable lines in them and I need to separate the two.
I have to count all the lines that have an Asterisk in position 7.  These are comments.  A simple calculation of total lines minus comment lines will provide the last artifact I need which is executable lines.
Can someone help out with altering the below code to just count Asterisk in position 7.

Thank you in advance,
-Ron

```
$path='C:\'
$outputFile='C:\Output.csv'
$include='*.cbl'
$exclude=''


param([string]$path, [string]$outputFile, [string]$include, [string]$exclude)
Clear-Host
Get-ChildItem -re -in $include -ex $exclude $path |
Foreach-Object { Write-Host "Counting '$($_.Name)'" 
    $fileStats = Get-Content $_.FullName | Measure-Object -line
    $linesInFile = $fileStats.Lines
    "$_,$linesInFile" } | Out-File $outputFile -encoding "UTF8"
Write-Host "Complete"
```

Comment: Is the comment just an Asterisk or is it an Asterisk followed by a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
$linesInFile = 0
switch -Regex -File $_.FullName {
    '^.{6}\*' { <# don't count this line #> }
    default   { $linesInFile++ }
}
```

This also should be faster than using Get-Content.

P.S. Also adding `-File` to the `Get-ChildItem` helps to eliminate processing directories.

Comment: I will give it a try - Thank you!

Comment: @user3166462 Great, let us know. This will count all lines _except_ the comment lines. No need to calculate total minus comments afterwards.